Como puedo formular que se repita el conteo de un caracter
Necesito pasar a un script esta formula que arme en Sheets:
=SI(BC2="","",SI(CONTAR.SI(BC2:BE2,0)>=1,0,1))

necesito contar cuantos ceros hay en un rango de columnas de forma eficiente.

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

que significa mas eficiente? o que esperas que se logre con decir que deba ser eficiente?

Paso un script que cuenta ceros  de un rango específico.
si haces la llamada a la función
getCounterCero()
retorna el número de ceros del rango por defecto 'Hoja 1!BC2:BE2'
puedes hacer otra llamada con otro rango
getCounterCero('Hoja 3!A1:Z100');
retorna los ceros de ese rango.
/**
 * Cuenta número de ceros
 * @param {range} range a evaluar defaults 'Hoja 1!BC2:BE2'
 * @returns {integer} número de ceros
 */
function getCounterCero(range='Hoja 1!BC2:BE2'){
  let countCero = 0;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRangeByName(range).getValues()
          .forEach(function(row){return row.forEach(function(column){ 
                              if(column == 0){countCero++;}})});
  console.log(countCero);
return countCero;}  /*  End function  */


Hola, buena respuesta, te recomendaria si no tienes suficiente informacion dejarle comentarios al usuario antes de dar una respuesta, ya que algunos usuarios en la comunidad pueden ver mal el que hayas respondido sin un contexto completo. saludos.

Hola Francisco IA, entiendo tu comentario pero que hay de malo en mostrar código que no es explicito a la pregunta pero das conocimiento y puede que tenga otra duda y el código ayuda resolverlo. Un saludo

no he dicho eso, Estoy de acuerdo en agregar codigo adiciponal e informacion relacionada que fortalesca el conocimiento de las personas, pero inicialmente si no hay una base o un contexto completo para dar una respuesta no es recomendado, si el usuario comenta algo o edita su post tu respuesta podria quedar invalidada...
